# How do I use variable inside a parentheses and single quotes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 I am trying to put a variable inside a (' ')

Orignial string

```
r = search.query('Hello World')
```

What I have tried so far and is not working...

```
r = search.query('{0}').format(company_name_search)

r = search.query('s%') % (company_name_search)
```

Both methods are not working and output the error below. What is the best way to take r = search.query('Hello World') and put a variable for Hello World so I can dynamically change the search parameters at will?

AttributeError: 'Results' object has no attribute 'format'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Results' and 'str'

Comment: `.format` or `%` are both valid, but must be applied to the string *inside* the surrounding parentheses: `search.query('{0}'.format(company_name_search))`, or 
`search.query('s%' % company_name_search)`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That's an answer. Please post it as the one for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now applying the `.format()` or `%` to the ***query()***. Apply them to the ***string***. `'{0}'.format(company_name_search)` or `'%s'%(company_name_search)`. Then throw that into the query function, like

```py
r = search.query('{0}'.format(company_name_search))

r = search.query('s%' % (company_name_search))
```